# Twilio:Transcript a record into text (python)

Tags: python, scripting, twilio, transcription

I have to script a little monitoring tool which make a outbound call to a hotline to see if everything is working as expected.

Goal: Call to the Hotline, record 20 seconds, transcribe the record into text, do a match. 
to do an Outbound call and record it is very simple. The problem I have is the transcription of the record. There is a Code snippet how you can make a transcription, but I dont know how to use it.

My Script to make an Outbound call and record the call:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.http.http_client import TwilioHttpClient

proxy_client = TwilioHttpClient()
proxy_client.session.proxies = {'https": "https://...'}

account_sid = 'ACXXXX'
auth_token = 'f00XXXXX'

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token, http_client=proxy_client)
call = client.calls.create(
                    record=True,
                    url='http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
                    to='+49000'
                    from_='+180000'
                )
```

The Code snippet from the Twilio Doku how to transcribe:

```
from Twilio.twiml.voice_response Import Record, VoiceResponse

from twilio.twiml.voice_response import Record, VoiceResponse

response = VoiceResponse()
response.record(timeout=10, transcribe=True)

print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet matches the [code sample](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record?code-sample=code-transcribe-a-recording-3&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x) except you are missing the transcribeCallback, which will let you know when you transcription is completed. You can pass in a webhook URL, so Twilio can alert you of this step.

You can [responsd to a statusCallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#status-callbacks-in-your-response) using a 204 or a 200 with an empty TwiML response. statusCallbacks do not process TwiML for call flow control, but you can use a REST API call to [modify an existing call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress-python), if required.

Alan

Comment: Hey Alan, thanks for the quick answer. What I dont understand how the Code is working together. In the upper code I say record = True. The call will recorded and stored in the console in 'Programmable Voice/ Recordings/ Recording logs'. What know I have to do in the code snipped? I dont know how where to put the record as a param, so that the transcription Begins. In the Console I dont have any entries in Transcription Logs.

Comment: Ahh, got it. Yes the Twilio transcription only works with the TwiML Record Verb. So you are using recording on the outbound-api request which doesn't work with the Twilio transcription (it does with some of add-in partners- https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133027-Transcribe-entire-phone-calls-with-Twilio, but they provided the transcription via a statusCallback. So, the URL of your outbound API call will reference TwiML which uses the TwiML Record verb with transcription enabled, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record.